# Visual Studio is out of memory?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

While I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 out of memory exception is thrown if I try to copy or cut any code.

So I cant copy any lines any more until restart it.

Any ideas of why is this happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a hotfix for it, but the simplest solution is to install [VS2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5) which fixes that amongst other things.

Answer (score 8):

That is a bug and MS already provided [a patch](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=29729).

Edit:

In the same time we can call it a feature because it disallows common programming patterns:

- Copy & paste development
- Copy & paste inheritance

Just joke ...

Comment: +1 - Some of the software that I have had to maintain in the past could have really used this feature during their development!

Answer (score 0):

There's a [fix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/25/patch-available-for-cut-or-copy-displaying-insufficient-memory-error-in-vs-2010.aspx) for your woes :)